# How should we tag questions about English-language literature?

Tags: discussion, tags

[After](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/261/17) a [lot](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/290/17) of [different](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/448/17) questions about the issue of tags based on languages and/or countries, we eventually [came to the conclusion](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/363/17) that **tags such as [russian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-literature) are useful** even on questions about specific works; furthermore, we also [clarified](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/648/17) that such tags should refer to ***languages* and not countries or cultures**, since the latter can sometimes be much harder to define.

However, there's an important special case still unresolved. In all of these discussions, we've made an exception, implicitly or explicitly, for works of literature written in *English*. The question [Should we have language-specific tags (excluding one for English)?](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/312/17) (which I've now voted to close as a dupe, by the way) has the caveat right there in the title, and [my answer here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/648/17) also deliberately skirts around the issue of English-language literature.

However, we now have an [american-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-literature) tag with 16 questions, so perhaps it's time to actually have this debate and work out what we want. As I see it, there are three options:

1. use a [english-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-literature) tag for all questions about literature in the English language;
2. use tags like [american-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/american-literature) and [australian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-literature) for different English-speaking subcultures;
3. don't tag English-language questions at all, with the implicit assumption that if a question about a book doesn't have a language tag, then it was written in English.

### Which of these routes should we take, and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option #2 is right out.

- **Inconsistency is the devil.** If we're using language-based instead of country-based tags for non-English languages, we shouldn't turn around and use country-based tags for English. That's just inconsistent and confusing.
- **Most of these areas also produce non-English literature.** Shouldn't a question about Aborigine literature be tagged with [australian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australian-literature)? Or a question about Scots Gaelic literature tagged with [scottish-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scottish-literature)? This relates to the previous bullet point, but it shows why inconsistency is dangerous - because there's overlap.
- **The same reasons as before.** Many of the issues I described [here](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/648/17) would still be issues if we used country-based tags for English literature. Take a book like Neil Gaiman's *American Gods* - it was written by an English author living in America, set in America but (I believe) more popular in Britain. In many cases, you can't even look at the book to decide whether it's written in (e.g.) British or American English, as you can with language tags, because there are editions in both.

### Option #1 feels unnecessary.

I could go either way on this, honestly, but a single overarching [english-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-literature) tag would probably be used on the majority of *all* our questions, which feels a bit over-the-top. Especially when instead of having a specific tag to mark these questions, they could just be marked by *the absence of any other language tag*.

Besides, are we likely to have any users who are experts in English literature as a whole and will want to search that tag? Far more likely, surely, that they'll be experts in some specific subcategory.

Comment: Yep, this makes sense. I'll wait a few days to a week to see if there aren't any objections, and then I'll edit out the [tag:american-literature] tag.

Comment: There's also a [tag:victorian-literature] tag, a [tag:childrens-literature] tag, and a [tag:irish-literature] tag (which isn't used for texts written in Irish). The third tag makes sense to remove per this consensus; what about the first two?

Comment: @Hamlet I think [tag:victorian-literature] is too ill-defined to work well as a tag (is it for books written in English during Victoria's reign? only those published in the empire she ruled? ...) But I hate the whole concept of naming periods of history after monarchs, so I may be biased there. As for [tag:childrens-literature], might be different enough to warrant a new meta post. Also worth noting that currently the only question with that tag is about the concept of children's lit, not just one specific book. Maybe the tag could be useful for that purpose, if it has a clear wiki guidance?

Comment: So the answer is option 3?

Comment: @Catija That's my proposal, yes. (Option 1 would also be OK, but I prefer 3.)

Comment: I agree with option 3 but I feel like your answer doesn't actually say that anywhere? I think [tag:english-literature] would be a meta tag because it'd end up on probably 80% of the questions here... if the site is *in* English, I think that it's fair to assume any question that doesn't have a [tag:n-language] tag is about an English book or a version of a non-English book that is in English... so if you read *The Odyssey* in English and weren't interested in original text, that would also default to English.

Comment: @Catija [tag:english-literature] isn't a *meta* tag, any more than [tag:french-literature] or [tag:spanish-literature]. The site is in English, but English literature is no more on-topic than literature in any other language; it just happens to be what most users have read most of. And yes, I haven't explicitly concluded that option 3 is the one to go for ... but if people can't "read between the lines" on [literature.se], where can they? :-P

Comment: Any tag that appears on a significant portion of a site's question has the *potential* to be a meta tag. Explaining why a couple of options are bad or less useful does not mean that you actually *support* the remaining one... you could simply have nothing to say about it and are hoping that someone comes up with a fourth option.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer now that Hamlet has removed the [tag:american-literature] and [tag:irish-literature] questions from the site.